# Resource for learning Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'm clearly in need of improving my knowledge in this Java field, or I'm doomed to produce "look the same but not exactly" code.
I'm already have the bases... but I'm looking for a training / tuturial oriented only to this.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like this should perhaps be a Community Wiki.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [book](http://books.google.fi/books?id=3keGb40PWJsC&dq=java+generics+wadler&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=fi&ei=PlwMSpj4IITL-Abh8uyiBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#PPP1,M1) written by one of the designers of Java Generics, Philip Wadler

Comment: +1 Naftalin & Wadler's book is, by far, the best resource on this difficult subject.

Comment: Woow. A whole books for the subject ? Classy.

Answer (score 23):

- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).
- [Oracle's Java Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)
- Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://www.infoq.com/articles/bloch-effective-java-2e), [Chapter 5 - Generics](http://www.infoq.com/resource/articles/bloch-effective-java-2e/en/resources/Bloch_Ch05.pdf) [pdf]

Comment: Effective java sounds like a great books,i will have to buy it.  Thanks for the chapter.

Comment: Effective Java links are not valid anymore, please update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

for a good and short introduction I recommend the PDF [Generics in the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) by [Gilad Bracha](http://bracha.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you're missing out on some design patterns and refactoring techniques. There's not really any way to learn this over night, but if you read up on some of the design patterns that are out there, it might get you thinking about how you could write code to be a little more generic and reusable.

- [Design Patterns for Java](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/)
- [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/)
- [Generics in the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) (PDF)
- [10 Tips on Writing Reusable Code](http://hoskinator.blogspot.com/2006/06/10-tips-on-writing-reusable-code.html)

Comment: i'v read tree of this resource ( two times for the head first ... ) and no, it's more generics than pattern who misse to my developper toolbox. 
( And the sun generics tutorial is a bit dry )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting Cay Horstmann's book 'Big Java'. This is the book that I have used for all 3 of my college Java courses.

[http://www.amazon.com/Big-Java-Cay-S-Horstmann/dp/0470105542/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470105542)

Answer (score 0):

You seek the one called [Skeet](http://www.skeetoverflow.com/search/?q=generics).

I've learned more about generics reading his answers to questions tagged Generics than in any book.

Comment: I'd vote you down for a gratuitous Skeet joke, but it's true. :|