# Java: returning subclass in superclass method signature

Tags: java, interface, subclass, superclass

I'm working on a problem where there are several implementations of `Foo`, accompanied by several `FooBuilder`'s. While `Foo`'s share several common variables that need to be set, they also have distinct variables that require their respective `FooBuilder` to implement some specific functionality. For succinctness, I'd like to have the `FooBuilder`'s setters to use method chaining, like:

```
public abstract class FooBuilder {
  ...

  public FooBuilder setA(int A) {
    this.A = A;
    return this;
  }

  ...
}
```

and

```
public class FooImplBuilder extends FooBuilder{
  ...
  public FooImplBuilder setB(int B) {
    this.B = B;
    return this;
  }
  public FooImplBuilder setC(int C) {
    this.C = C;
    return this;
  }
  ...
}
```

And so on, with several different `FooBuilder` implementations. This technically does everything I want, however, this approach is sensitive to the order of methods calls when method chaining is performed. The following has method undefined compile errors:

```
someFoo.setA(a).setB(b)...
```

Requiring that the developer think about the order of method calls in the chain. To avoid this, I'd like to have the setters in `FooBuilder` somehow return the actual implementing subclass. However, I'm not sure how to do this. What is the best approach?

Comment: Also, it either forces casting everywhere, or it prevents you from changing properties of superclasses when you want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a good question and a real problem.

The easiest way to deal with it in Java likely involves the use of generics, as mentioned in Jochen's answer.

There's a good discussion of the issue and a reasonable solution in this blog entry on [Using Inheritance with Fluent Interfaces](http://egalluzzo.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-inheritance-with-fluent.html), which combines generics with the definition of a `getThis()` method overriden in builder subclasses to solve the problem of always returning a builder of the correct class.

Comment: I like this solution. A lot more elaborate than what I proposed, but also way more flexible and ultimately elegant.

Comment: Just to summarize the linked blog, and remove the separate builders: `public abstract class X<B extends X<?>>{public int a;public B setA(int foo){this.a=foo;return getThis();}public abstract B getThis();}public class Y extends X<Y>{public int b;public Y setB(int bar){this.b=bar;return getThis();}public Y getThis(){return this;}}`

Answer (score 16):

Having found [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603485) I am now sharing it around.

```java
public class SuperClass<I extends SuperClass>
{
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" ) // If you're annoyed by Lint.
    public I doStuff( Object withThings )
    {
        // Do stuff with things.
        return (I)this ; // Will always cast to the subclass. Causes the Lint warning.
    }
}

public class ImplementationOne
extends SuperClass<ImplementationOne>
{} // doStuff() will return an instance of ImplementationOne

public class ImplementationTwo
extends SuperClass<ImplementationTwo>
{} // doStuff() will return an instance of ImplementationTwo
```

Comment: `SuperClass<I extends SuperClass<I>>` to get  rid of "Raw use of parameterized class ..."

Answer (score 5):

Generics might be the way to go here.

If you declare setA() something like this (pseudo-code)

```
<T> T setA(int a)
```

the compiler should be able to figure out the real types, and if it doesn't you can give hints in the code like

```
obj.<RealFoo>setA(42)
```

Comment: +1: There's a good description of this tactic at http://egalluzzo.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-inheritance-with-fluent.html

Comment: The compiler is *not* able to figure out the type in chained method invocation, and repeating the type for each method invocation is hardly an option.

Comment: @DonRoby: Why don't you post that as an answer? It happens to be a better solution than Jochen's and would surely deserve an upvote ;-)