# Automatic cast to subclass in getter/setter

Tags: java, oop

I have a rather weird question. Consider the following two classes:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private Node<T> parent;
    private Node<T> left;
    private Node<T> right;
    private T data;

    public Node(Node<T> parent, T data) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node<T> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Node<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(Node<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class RedBlackNode<T> extends Node<T> {

    private Color color;

    public RedBlackNode(Node<T> parent, T data) {
        super(parent, data);
        this.color = Color.Black;
    }

    public RedBlackNode(Node<T> parent, T data, Color color) {
        super(parent, data);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

My question is .. is there any way in which I could write:

```
RedBlackNode<Whatever> x = y.getLeft();
```

where y is a `RedBlackNode` without having to specifically cast using:

```
RedBlackNode<Whatever> x = (RedBlackNode<Whatever>) y.getLeft();
```

and also, without having to override the getters/setters in the RedBlackNode class?

I mean, I just want to somehow make the RedBlackNode be "aware" that it's a RedBlackNode and know that all its children/parent are actually RedBlackNodes as well. I am not sure but maybe somehow add a new abstraction layer on top of the Node class somehow maybe?

Ty!

Later edit:

Thank you for all your prompt answers, this is what I have so far:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode<T, U extends AbstractNode<T, U>> {
    private AbstractNode<T, U> parent;
    private AbstractNode<T, U> left;
    private AbstractNode<T, U> right;
    private T data;

    public AbstractNode(AbstractNode<T, U> parent, T data) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public AbstractNode<T, U> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(AbstractNode<T, U> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public AbstractNode<T, U> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(AbstractNode<T, U> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public AbstractNode<T, U> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(AbstractNode<T, U> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

public class RedBlackNode<T extends Element> extends AbstractNode<Element, RedBlackNode<Element>> {

    private Color color;

    public RedBlackNode(RedBlackNode<Element> parent, T data) {
        super(parent, data);
        this.color = Color.Black;
    }

    public RedBlackNode(RedBlackNode<Element> parent, T data, Color color) {
        super(parent, data);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}


public class Node<T> extends AbstractNode<T, Node<T>> {

    public Node(AbstractNode<T, Node<T>> parent, T data) {
        super(parent, data);
    }

}
```

However, I need to create 2 types of trees. A simple Binary Search Tree which has as nodes only instances of class Node and, as expected, a Red Black Tree which has only instances of RedBlackNode as nodes.

I made an abstract class for these trees (with many more methods, this is the trimmed version) but I fear that I am missing something as I seem to have this `Node<Element>` as the generic type in the class definition.

```
public abstract class Tree<T extends AbstractNode<Element, Node<Element>>> {

    protected T root;

    public T getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }

    public abstract T search(T n, int key);

    public abstract T insert(Element e, T cRoot);
}
```

What am I missing here? How to best model this?

---

Later edit 2:

I currently have:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode<E extends Element, U extends AbstractNode<E, U>> {
    private U parent;
    private U left;
    private U right;
    private E data;

    public AbstractNode(U parent, E data) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public U getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(U parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public U getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(U left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public U getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(U right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

public class Node<E extends Element> extends AbstractNode<E, Node<E>> {

    public Node(Node<E> parent, E data) {
        super(parent, data);
    }

}

public class RedBlackNode<E extends Element> extends AbstractNode<E, RedBlackNode<E>> {

    private Color color;

    public RedBlackNode(RedBlackNode<E> parent, E data) {
        super(parent, data);
        this.color = Color.Black;
    }

    public RedBlackNode(RedBlackNode<E> parent, E data, Color color) {
        super(parent, data);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

The Tree class:

```
public abstract class Tree<E extends Element, T extends AbstractNode<E, T>> {

    protected T root;

    public T getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }

    public abstract T search(T n, int key);
}
```

AND The `BinarySearchTreeClass`

```
public class BinarySearchTree<Element> extends Tree<Element, Node<Element>> {

    @Override
    public Node<Element> search(Node<Element> n, int key) {
        if (n == null || n.getData().getIntegerData() == key) {
            return n;
        }
        return key < n.getData().getIntegerData() ? search(  n.getLeft(), key) : search( n.getRight(), key);
    }

}
```

Why in the world am I getting `Bound mismatch: The type Element is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Element> of the type Node<E>`. It's `E extends Element`. Doesn't that mean it can be of type `Element` as well?
Nevertheless, I tried using something like a separate class which extended `Element` but to no avail..

Also, I am getting a `The type parameter Element is hiding the type Element` and I have no idea why..

I created a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Alex-Cosma/3378f475adb78a42c2c0) for this.

Comment: The simplest solution (yet boilerplate) is to override super class methods and change return type to `RedBlackNode`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there any way to avoid overriding those methods?

Comment: Perhaps if you extract the boilerplate code and add it as an interface with generics?  So you implement NodeGetters<Node> for the Node and NodeGetters<RedBlackNode> or a parent class.

Comment: Yes, but they suck :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968557/java-returning-subclass-in-superclass-method-signature

Comment: Your abstract class does not have the right generics.  See SamYonnou's example: `AbstractNode<T, U extends AbstractNode<T, U>>`.  The `T` is the type of the data in each node.  The `U` - I'd have called it `N` personally - is the type of the associated nodes (parent, left and right) which are of type `U extends AbstractNode<T,U>` (which is to say "some subtype of `AbstractNode` where `T` is the data in it, and its related nodes (parent, left, right) are also of type `U`").  If that all sounds a bit recursive, that's because it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind pulling `Node` out into an abstract class you can specify the type as part of the generic signature like so:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode<T, U extends AbstractNode<T, U>> {
    ...
    public U getLeft() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

// inherited getLeft() will return Node<T>
public class Node<T> extends AbstractNode<T, Node<T>> { ... }

// inherited getLeft() will return RedBlackNode<T>
public class RedBlackNode<T> extends AbstractNode<T, RedBlackNode<T>> { ... }
```

Edit: for your trees you would either create a separate tree for each node type, or if you want to reuse base functionality you could do something like:

```
// base functionality goes here, T is the element type, U is the node type
public abstract class Tree<T, U extends AbstractNode<T, U>> { ... }

public class BinarySearchTree<T> extends Tree<T, Node<T>> { ... }

public class RedBlackTree<T> extends Tree<T, RedBlackNode<T>> { ... }
```

or if you just want to share the method signatures then make `Tree` an interface instead of an abstract class. Or better yet, have a `Tree` interface and an `AbstractTree` abstract class that implements shared functionality.

Comment: That should work.  We use this approach in a fluent form component library, allowing each component to be aware of, and to return, its own type for method chaining.

Comment: +1, however, I'd recommend that we use `This` as the conventional name for such type parameters; and lose the bound. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382847/avoiding-generic-types-of-form-fooactualtype-extends-fooactualtype/30656295#30656295

Comment: Is it really conventional?  I've never seen that use before.  I wouldn't personally as `This` will look suspiciously like a class name.  And it *is* conventional to use a single uppercase letter for generic type arguments, in most cases.  I'd use `N` (for node).

Comment: @Paul - not conventional yet, but that's what I'm proposing :)

Comment: What bound are you suggesting losing?  I can't see anything that can be dropped that leaves this still working.

Comment: @Paul I think he means do `AbstractNode<T, This extends AbstractNode>` instead of `AbstractNode<T, This extends AbstractNode<T, This>>`

Comment: That won't work because when you assign to a `RedBlackNode<ConcreteThing>` variable the result of calling `getLeft()` (for example) the compiler won't know about the `ConcreteThing` part in the assignment.  It will result in a warning at least.  I don't remember if it is an outright compiler error.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your wonderful responses. Check out my latest edit of the problem.

Comment: @Paul - I mean `AbstractNode<T, This>`. The bound of `This` is often not needed; as in this case.

Comment: Re edits.  Shouldn't `BinarySearchTree<T> extends Tree<T, Node<T>>` be `BinarySearchTree<T> extends Tree<T, BinarySearchNode<T>>`?

Comment: @Paul I think OP was saying that he would use the `Node` type for the BST implementation, although I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @bayou.io Still don't see how the recursive bounds can be left out.  (See my comment above mentioning `ConcreteThing`.)  However, I haven't seen a complete set of your definitions using `AbstractNode<T, This>` so I have to infer the rest.

Comment: @Paul - the bound doesn't exactly work - e.g. you can declare `RedBlackNode<T> extends AbstractNode<T, Node<T>>`.

Comment: Again, I added some new info on the latest edit. This is driving me crazy

Comment: @Alexandr if `Element` is a concrete type not a generic then you don't write `BinarySearchTree<Element> extends Tree<Element, Node<Element>>` but instead `BinarySearchTree extends Tree<Element, Node<Element>>` or if you meant to use a generic type then `BinarySearchTree<E extends Element> extends Tree<E, Node<E>>`